flightPHP - Active Record relations issue with setup?
I have 2 tables, users and roles, as follows:
USERS                  ROLES
-----------------------------
id                     id
role_id                name
fname                  ... 
...                    

How do I properly setup the relation between the 2?
In my mapper Users extends \flight\ActiveRecord I have this constructor:

function __construct($databaseConnection) {
     $this->relations = [
        'role' => [ self::HAS_ONE, \Main\Models\Roles::class, 'id' ]
     ];
     parent::__construct($databaseConnection, 'users');
}


Based on the docs online, when I run this code in my controller
$user = $this->mapper->find(7);
I'd expect to have $user->role->name with the name of the role assigned to user with id=7 but instead it's NULL.
To pull the correct role name I need to run the following block:
$user = $this->mapper->find(7);
$user->role->find($user->getData()['role_id'])->getData();

and only then I have the proper value in $user->role->name.
Is this how this feature is meant to work or am I doing something wrong in my mapper?
Thank you.

I think I see the issue. Based on looking at the docs here it looks like that should reference the local key rather than foreign key id.
So your code should be this:
function __construct($databaseConnection) {
     $this->relations = [
        'role' => [ self::BELONGS_TO, \Main\Models\Roles::class, 'role_id' ]
     ];
     parent::__construct($databaseConnection, 'users');
}

Hope on the chat if you have any further questions!

Hi n0nag0n, No that's not it, if I change that to role_id I get an SQL error, SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.role_id' in 'where clause' and if I check the query, it's select roles.* from roles where role_id = something but roles does not have a role_id column, it's got id, role_id is in the users' table as a FK to the roles table. Thank you anyway for your answer.

I got it all wrong, thanks for pointing it out. So basically, in my Users mapper I should have this
        'role' => [ self::BELONGS_TO, \Main\Models\Roles::class, 'role_id' ]
       ];``` 
   instead of 
   ``` $this->relations = [
        'role' => [ self::HAS_ONE, \Main\Models\Roles::class, 'id' ]
    ];``` 
and now if I run 
``` $user = $this->mapper->find(7);
 var_dump($user->role->name);``` 
I get my role name without the need of running `$user->role->find($user->getData()['role_id'])->getData();`

At least you got to the right answer eventually! I'll change my answer to reflect that too!
